# 10A/115V Jumper

Tags: pcb, design, components, jumper

What component would you use for a 10A/115V jumper header (I need the user to be able to choose among a few power settings)? I have relatively small space on the PCB and I am also trying to be reasonably cheap.

Comment: 10A/115V jumper? Your looking at a switch or a relay. Jumping mains at that amperage?

Comment: Yes, thanks, indeed. A switch. There is no need to do this online (the device is going to be switched off for a reconfiguration). I have a power logger and the LEM Hall effect current sensor that I use can be configured for a different amperage so I want to allow the user to do that based on what device the power logger is connected to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0.156" (3.96mm) header with a female connector with jumpers in it is one way. Ratings by [Molex](http://www.mouser.com/new/molex/molex-kk/) are as much as 13A. You'll have to check that the clearances meet the requirements of whatever safety standards you have to meet.

Photo from [here](http://allelcdn.upshotcommerce.com//mas_assets/cache/image/4/3/c/480x480-1084.Jpg)
[image: http://allelcdn.upshotcommerce.com//mas_assets/cache/image/4/3/c/480x480-1084.Jpg]

You could have different female connectors with wires looped between different pins.

If the clearances/creepage distances are insufficient to meet the safety standards you can slot the board or skip a pin.

Answer (score 2):

A thick wire!!! can't be more cheaper than that. Use your soldering iron to switch.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, but it is not very convenient, user (even if I am the user) has to open the box, unscrew the PCB, etc., etc. I prefer a switch.

Comment: I don't quite get it... Why don't you use a switch then?

Answer (score 1):

If the "jumper" will actually be carrying 10 Amps at 120V, then you need fairly thick wires, in a safe way. You can either control a mechanical or solid state relay via low voltage control, or you need a switch.

At that current and voltage, a typical residential power switch (On/On spdt) would do nicely. And cheap.